# Writing Windows Phone Runtime Components in C#?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8, winprt

Is it possible to write Windows Phone 8 Runtime Components in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible at this time.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible according to these articles, but sadly only project template in C++ is currently available for Windows (Phone) Runtime Component:
[Creating Windows Runtime Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441572.aspx)  (Windows 8)
[Share using Windows Runtime Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714080%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (Windows Phone 8)

Comment: If you read your second link, you'll realize that it's **not** possible.

Comment: I read the second link carefully and there's nowhere that says explicitly that it's not possible to create a component in C#, but I thought I'd read it somewhere...

Comment: @PaulAnnetts the table under "Creating and consuming Windows Runtime Components" only lists C++ under languages in which you can write windows phone runtime components.